# How can i create a new iCal event from file names in a folder?

Tags: macos, applescript, icalendar, automator

Usually i quickly update my TODO list creating a new empty file named like this:

```
2013-10-01 Tell a friend that stackoverflow rocks
2013-10-23 Prepare my super meeting about coding
```

and so on..

i just need a workflow or applescript that take all file in the folder, extract the date and the title from the file name and creates a new iCal event on that day with that title!

it seems so easy, but how can i achieve that?

Comment: i'm trying to use automator but cannot find any useful solution for using the date extracted from the filename as day for the event.. neither use the rest of filename as title. i was thinking about using applescript, but i'm quite newbie on it..

Answer (score 1):

Here's something in straight Applescript.

Note: It depends on you changing your date format to DD-MM-YYYY  (due to Applescripts in built date parser)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set data_folder to folder POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/my_ical_data"
    set all_items to every item of data_folder
end tell

set my text item delimiters to {" "}

repeat with cur_item in all_items
    set nm to the name of cur_item
    set event_date to date (text item 1 of nm)
    set event_desc to (text items 2 thru -1 of nm) as string
    tell application "iCal"
        tell calendar "Work" -- name of calendar you wish to add to
            make new event with properties {summary:event_desc, start date:event_date, description:""}
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Hey @Khalizar did any of these answers work for you? Would be great to close the question or share your own final answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does not require you to change the date format in System Preferences:

```
tell application "Finder" to name of items of folder POSIX file "/Users/username/todo"
repeat with l in result
    set s to text ((offset of space in l) + 1) thru -1 of l
    set d to current date
    tell d to set {year, month, date, time} to {text 1 thru 4 of s, text 6 thru 7 of s, text 9 thru 10 of s, 0}
    tell application "iCal" to tell calendar "Work"
        make new event with properties {summary:s, start date:d}
    end tell
end repeat
```